Shipment Allocation using Pulp
I am trying to create a model where each shipment must be allocated to a route to minimize the freight cost. I am a complete newbie at LP Optimization.
Explanation of dataset:

Every destination (D1,D2 etc) is mapped to a particular route.
The freight cost is specific to the route.

The shipments have to be allotted in the following manner -
For example: between R2 and R3, if shipment 1007431200 is picked for R3, R2 should not be picked.
Below is a small sample of my dataset.

The following is one of my models that I have created. However, I am not getting appropriate results validated by my business stakeholders.
routes = ['R1', 'R2', 'R3']  # List of routes
destinations = ['WD1', 'WD2', 'WD3', 'WD4']  # List of destination points
route_freight_cost = {  # Dictionary of freight cost per route
    'R1': 10000,
    'R2': 8000,
    'R3': 12000,
}

# Create LP problem
problem = LpProblem("ShipmentAllocation", LpMinimize)

# Decision variables (route selection)
route_selection = LpVariable.dicts("RouteSelection", routes, cat="Binary")

# Decision variables (shipment assignment)
shipment_vars = LpVariable.dicts("Shipment", [(r, d) for r in routes for d in destinations], cat="Binary")

# Objective function (minimize total freight cost)
problem += lpSum(route_selection[r] * route_freight_cost[r] for r in routes)

# Constraint 1: Each shipment assigned to exactly one route
for d in destinations:
    problem += lpSum(shipment_vars[(r, d)] for r in routes) == 1

# Constraint 2: A route can only be selected if at least one shipment is assigned to it
for r in routes:
    problem += lpSum(shipment_vars[(r, d)] for d in destinations) >= route_selection[r]

# Constraint 3: All WDs (destinations) must be served by at least one route (assuming WD is in 'destinations' list)
for d in destinations:
    problem += lpSum(shipment_vars[(r, d)] for r in routes) >= 1

# Solve the problem
problem.solve()


In constraint 1 you stated that each shipment must be assigned to exactly one route but you're iterating over destinations (which essentially makes constraint 3 also redundant). Side note, you're creating more variables than needed in shipment_vars. Every route doesn't have every destination and you can have a lot fewer variables by constructing that variable correctly, only keeping those indexes that exist (e.g., R2 only appears in D1)
